# UITextView border not appearing

Tags: objective-c, ios7

```
- (void)setupTextviewBorder {
self.descTextView.layer.borderWidth = 50.0;
float f = 197.0/255.0;
self.descTextView.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:f green:f blue:f alpha:1]);
self.descTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
self.descTextView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
self.descTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

yes I am calling this method and I can log the layer. When I view it, I see no border.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
self.descTextView.layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor colorWithRed:f green:f blue:f alpha:1]);
```

To this:

```
self.descTextView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:f green:f blue:f alpha:1].CGColor;
```

Comment: From [this issue (link)](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/issues/195) on github, "the conversion is not defined, and prone to crash, since there is no toll-free conversion".